Mui migration date picker: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders
I'm migrating this monorepo app from React 16 to React 17 and also MUI 4 to MUI 5. Everything is working just fine, but I just hit a wall when trying to use the MUI 5 date picker. I'm getting this error:
../node_modules/@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider/LocalizationProvider.js 36:50
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:50)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     utils: parentUtils,
|     localeText: parentLocaleText
>   } = React.useContext(MuiPickersAdapterContext) ?? {
|     utils: undefined,
|     localeText: undefined

and this is my package.json
{
  "name": "miret-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --delete-dir-on-start --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.js,.tsx\" --source-maps both --copy-files --ignore \"src/static/pdfjs-2.0.943-dist\" ",
    "start": "babel src --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.js,.tsx\" --watch --source-maps both --copy-files",
    "storybook:build": "npm run build",
    "storybook:watch": "babel src --out-dir lib --extensions \".ts,.js,.tsx\" --watch --source-maps both --copy-files",
    "storybook:web": "start-storybook -s ./src/stories/static -p 6006",
    "jenkins-build": "npm run build",
    "jenkins-tsc": "tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck",
    "jenkins-tslint": "tslint -c tslint.json --project tsconfig.json 'src/**/*.ts*'",
    "test-watch": "yarn run build & jest --watch",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "deploy-storybook": "storybook-to-ghpages",
    "scss": "node-sass --watch src/ux/CalendarPage/BigCalendar/sass -o src/ux/CalendarPage/BigCalendar/css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.0.11",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.0.11",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.0.11",
    "@storybook/addon-options": "^5.0.11",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.0.11",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.0.11",
    "@storybook/storybook-deployer": "^2.8.1",
    "@storybook/theming": "^5.0.11",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/d3-color": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/invariant": "^2.2.29",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.2",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/mousetrap": "^1.6.0",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^12.1.2",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "^0.36.1",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/react-resize-detector": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.2.3",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/recompose": "^0.30.2",
    "@types/storybook-readme": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/storybook__addon-actions": "^3.4.1",
    "@types/storybook__addon-knobs": "^3.4.1",
    "@types/storybook__addon-links": "^3.3.2",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^3.0.9",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "storybook-readme": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.7.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^4.0.8",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^4.0.8",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^4.0.8",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@ret/retde-icons": "^1.7.0",
    "@ret/retde-iconsv2": "^1.6.5",
    "@ret/retde-iconsv3": "^5.1.0",
    "@ret/rivr-core": "2.0.42",
    "@ret/rivr-recorder": "2.0.42",
    "@ret/screenshot": "^1.0.0-beta.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.11",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.14",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.170",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/babel__core": "^7.1.3",
    "@types/babel__template": "^7.0.2",
    "@types/react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/react-window": "^1.8.2",
    "@types/react-window-infinite-loader": "^1.0.3",
    "@u-wave/react-vimeo": "^0.8.3",
    "apexcharts": "^3.28.1",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "bricks.js": "^1.8.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "cloudinary-react": "^1.1.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.8",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "d3-array": "^2.0.2",
    "d3-color": "^1.2.3",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "dompurify": "^1.0.9",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "is-url-external": "^1.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "miret-core": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.2",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "plotly.js": "^1.54.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.22.1",
    "react-calendar": "^2.19.1",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-hexagon": "^1.1.3",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "react-items-carousel": "^2.8.0",
    "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",
    "react-markdown": "^4.2.2",
    "react-masonry-component": "^6.2.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.5.5",
    "react-papaparse": "^3.11.0",
    "react-pdf": "^4.1.0",
    "react-plotlyjs": "^0.4.4",
    "react-resize-detector": "^6.6.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scroll": "^1.7.10",
    "react-sizeme": "^2.5.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "react-spinners": "^0.4.8",
    "react-step-progress-bar": "^1.0.3",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-to-print": "^2.0.0-alpha-6",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.21.2",
    "react-virtualized-auto-sizer": "^1.0.2",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "react-window-infinite-loader": "^1.0.5",
    "recharts": "^1.4.0",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0",
    "recyclerlistview": "^1.3.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "remark-breaks": "^1.0.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "vh-check": "^2.0.5",
    "video-react": "^0.13.6"
  }
}


I've tried everything I've found, including updating Babel to the newest version and TypeScript, but I still encounter the same problem. Then I noticed it could be due to webpack:
├─ react-scripts@3.4.4
│  └─ webpack@4.42.0
└─ webpack@4.46.0
✨  Done in 0.65s.

I updated react-scripts from version 3 to 5, but then I get a bunch of errors from node_modules about some imports not existing.
It seems this app is using react-app-rewired. Here's the config-overrides.js:
module.exports = function override(webpackConfig) {
  webpackConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.mjs$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    type: 'javascript/auto',
  });

  return webpackConfig;
};

and this is my .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {"modules": false}],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }], 
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "ux": "./src/ux",
        "components": "./src/components",
        "pages": "./src/pages"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "src/static/pdfjs-2.0.943-dist"
  ]
}

I tried adding all the Babel plugins, like @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator, but to no avail. Any ideas to try would be welcome. Thanks!
Did you find anything related to it please help!!!!
